# Bash:decrementing american date by 1 day mmddyyyy

Tags: date

To simplify the problem, lets say I have variable:
`dat="10152015"`  (representing 15th October 2015)
the result for `dat` should be `10142015`

Note that I am not using today's date.

What I have problem with is thinking of a way to decrement the date by 1 day. I could just decrement the 4th digit, but this is a calendar.

My current thinking is to convert this into a format that unix understands (whatever that is), then try working from there, and then convert the answer back

Answer (score 2):

requires GNU date:

```
dat="10152015"
date -d "${dat:4}${dat:0:4} yesterday" +%m%d%Y
```

`YYYYMMDD` is an ISO 9601 date format and the packed amercan format `MMDDYYYY` can be translated to that by simply swapping the two halves using ordinary substring expansion.

this requires gnu date, I don't think other versions of date support displaying non-current time.

Comment: It is indeed GNU specific, but note that FreeBSD date also supports displaying non-current time, but using a completely different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This first uses `sed` to convert the format you gave, 10152015, to the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, which the GNU implementation of the `date` command, with its `-d` options understands. This is accomplished by echoing the original date into `sed` which inserts the slashes `/`. This re-formatted date value is stored in `D`.  Next we call `date` with instructions to print the output format "mmddyyyy", and tell it to print the date of `yesterday` using `$D` as the current date.

```
#!/bin/sh
D=$(echo "${1-10152015}" | sed 's,^\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)$,\1/\2/\3,')
date +%m%d%Y -d"$D yesterday"
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is not the best shell for date calculation as its date-manipulation capabilities are very limited.

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
d=03012012
strftime -rs d %m%d%Y%H ${d}12
strftime %m%d%Y $((d-86400))
```

With `ksh93`:

```
d=03012012
printf "%(%m%d%Y)T\n" "${d:4}${d:0:4} yesterday"
```

With `bash`, you'd either have to do the calculation  by hand or rely on `perl` or some GNU or FreeBSD extensions of the `date` utility.

Answer (score 0):

@Jasen's elegant answer inspired me to think of this variation, also requiring GNU `date`:

```
#!/bin/sh

D=${1-10152015}

YYYY=${D#????}
MMDD=${D%????}

date -d"$YYYY$MMDD yesterday" +%m%d%Y
```

This uses the POSIX compliant Parameter Expansion substring processing with pattern matching notation, thus also runs under any POSIX `/bin/sh` as well as `bash`.

This could also be accomplished without the intermediate variables `YYYY` and `MMDD`, but I think they help to clearly document the input and output formats.  They give the observer an extra symbolic clue about what's being done, without the addition of extra logic.  Especially helpful because I think this notation is slightly more cryptic than the `bash` version.

Answer (score -1):

Note: the following assumes GNU date from GNU coreutils.  Adapt to your system's date if you have a different `date` utility.

Your thinking is correct, you need to convert to seconds since the epoch (Jan 1 1970 00:00:00).

GNU date is reasonably flexible in the date formats it will interpret, but MMDDYYYY is not one of them.  Fortunately, you can use sed to reformat the date (into YYYY-MM-DD format) before giving it to `date -d`

```sh
dat="10152015"
secs=$(date +%s -d $(echo "$dat" | sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)/\3-\1-\2/'))
newsecs=$((secs - 86400))
date -d "@$newsecs"
```

Comment: Actually, if you're going to use GNU `date`, you might as well get it do the calculation: `date -d "10/15/2015 - 1 day"`, for example, or `date -d "2015-10-15 - 1 day"`.

Comment: OTOH, converting to seconds-since-the-epoch and performing additions and subtractions on that is a tried-and-tested generic technique that works in every language that has even minimal date functions.

Comment: OTFH, it does rely on [assumptions about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Comment: yes. time is arbitary and everyone makes assumptions about it.  e.g. adding or subtracting 86400 won't work properly on a day with a leap-second, or on transition days to/from Daylight Savings

Comment: subtracting 24 hours is not reliable.  some days are 23 hours long, some 25.

Comment: @Jasen, on the other end, if you do it for the time as mid-day, it's relatively safe (except maybe if you're on some pacific island and on the very day your government decides to switch between GMT+12 and GMT-12 or along those lines).